# Event on logic value change

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I usually use the `@` operator to wait for any logical value change of a particular signal. For example to wait on any change in signal `a`, I usually do

```
wire a;
//...
@(a); // wait any value change 0->1 or 1->0, or x->1 etc
```

But now I realized that the above codes will not always work as expected especially when we introduce signal strength, as illustrated in following code:

```
module test;
  wire a;
  logic sweak1 = 0;
  logic spull1 = 0;

  assign (weak0,weak1) a = sweak1 ? 1'b1 : 1'bz;
  assign (pull0,pull1) a = spull1 ? 1'b1 : 1'bz;

  task wait_a_change();
    @(a);
  endtask

  initial forever begin
    $display("Value: a = %b %v @%0t", a, a, $time);
    wait_a_change();
    end
  initial begin
    sweak1 = 1;
    #10; spull1 = 1;
    #10; spull1 = 0;
    #10; spull1 = 1;
    #10;
   end 
endmodule
```

The event `@(a)` will trigger even if the logical value of `a` doesn't change.
So my first solution to overcome this is by doing:

```
task wait_a_change();
  if (a) @(negedge a);
  else   @(posedge a);
endtask
```

That solution requires additional check (and line too). 
Is there any better solution?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but note that `@(a)` can also fire in another case where `a` has not changed. This happens when there are zero-length glitches on `a`, and the initial and final values of `a` are the same. Some simulators will fire the event, and some won't. Using edges won't fix this - you'll need to manually check to confirm that the values differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@(!a)`. By putting it through a Boolean expression, it loses its strength. The only thing you loose is x->z transitions. (your solution would not catch that either). If you need that, you had better explain better what you are trying to accomplish, where might be an entirely different approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the 4-state value(1/0/X/Z) you can do `@(posedge a, negedge a)` or `@(posedge a or negedge a)`. I have seen at least one simulator with a bug that treat these the same as `@(a)`. If your simulator supports IEEE1800-2009 (SystemVerilog 2009) or higher, you can use `@(edge a)`. If all else fail, you can always sample the value with another wire.

```
wire a_val = a; // <-- 4-state value w/o preserving the strength
task wait_a_change();
  @(a_val);
endtask
```